# exception while changing cursor

Tags: wpf

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'filehelpertest.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

Hi all,
i'v wanted to change my grid's cursor to a custom one using this code:

```
        //using resources is already in the references assembly
        Cursor gameCursor = new Cursor(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pictures/Cursor.cur")).Stream);
        MenuGrid.Cursor = gameCursor;
```

but for some reason this exception jumps when im running the program.
the .cur file has been added to the project and marked as a resource.
any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using MenuGrid.OverrideCursor instead of MenuGrid.Cursor ?

Comment: yes, but the exception is in the line before. somthing with the path is wrong maybe?

Comment: You've put the code after InitializeComponent?

Comment: No. Does it make a diffrence?